# Nested routes error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

In my rails application I have this routes

```
resources :jobs do
  resources :job_applications, :path =>  'applications' do
    member do 
      put :change_stage
    end
  end
end
```

And I have a method called change_stage in my job_application controller
Actually I'm trying to change one params of the job_application in an modal so for this I have this in the modal body

```
<%=form_for :job_application, :url => change_stage_job_job_application.(params[:application_status]), :html => {:method => :post, :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

<%= label :status, 'reject' %>
<%= f.radio_button :application_status, 'reject' %><br>
<%= label :status, 'interview' %>
<%= f.radio_button :application_statuss, 'interview' %><br>
<%= label :status, 'hired' %>
<%= f.radio_button :application_status, 'hired' %>

<% end %>
```

but I'm getting this error

> ```
> undefined local variable or method `change_stage_job_application' for #<#<Class:0xb463b49c>:0xb463ac04>
> ```

What is wrong in my form

Answer (score 1):

1) Remove the dot between url's name and params

2) Concatenate _path after url's name.

3) As it is a member method for nested routes, pass both parameters job and job_application.

```
<%=form_for :job_application, :url => change_stage_job_job_application_path(@job, @job_application), :html => {:method => :post, :class => 'form-    horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `change_stage_job_job_application_path` (without dot at the end).

FYI: Will be better to check Rails URL helper name use `rake routes` for any case.

Comment: What I'm getting now is this error No route matches {:action=>"change_stage", :controller=>"job_applications", :id=>nil, :job_id=>nil, :locale=>:en} missing required keys: [:id, :job_id]

Comment: Definitely run `rake routes` and see exactly what parameters you need to pass with your helper to the controller. But from what I can see, I'm pretty sure you need to pass both the `job_application` and `job` instance variables. You don't need to pass the `application_status` since you will be able to get this trough the params hash on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have to mention that the idea behind creating resources in your routes is to use RESTful routes and let Rails infer the URL rather than forcing a URL in your form statement. From the APIdock: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

> However, further simplification is possible if the record passed to form_for is a resource, i.e. it corresponds to a set of RESTful routes, e.g. defined using the resources method in config/routes.rb. In this case Rails will simply infer the appropriate URL from the record itself.

Why not try removing the URL statement entirely and trust your routes?

About the nil error mentioned, I think this parameter

```
params[:application_status]
```

is stripping the rest of your hash vars so they're missing when it gets to the controller.